# CSS resize horizontal not working on Firefox

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS resize: horizontal to make my table heading resizable. It is working perfectly on Chrome and Opera Browser while it is not working on Firefox Browser.

```
  <th class="text-left pl-2 resize-table">
       <label>Project Name</label>
       <span class="pull-right">
         <i class="fal fa-arrow-up sortClass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </span>
   </th>
```

**CSS**

```
.resize-table {
  overflow: auto;
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

Comment: Try `-moz-resize: horizontal;`

Comment: read compatibility here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

Comment: are you using <iframe> because **resize doesn't have any effect on <iframe> in firefox**

Comment: I am using resize inside the th of the table to make table's column resizable. I found that it's a bug on Firefox. The resizable does not work inside the table in Firefox Browser. https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8120

Answer (score 0):

Place the header content inside a div. And then make the div resizable:

```
<th class="text-left pl-2">
   <div class="resize-table">
       <label>Project Name</label>
       <span class="pull-right">
         <i class="fal fa-arrow-up sortClass" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </span>
   </div>
</th>
```